# Consequences of a distillation algorithm for PSPACE

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, parameterized-complexity, polynomial-hierarchy, pspace

The following notion of a distillation algorithm comes from "On Problems Without Polynomial Kernels".

> Let a language $L$ be given.  A **distillation algorithm** for $L$ takes a given
>   list of input strings $\{ x_i \}_{i \in [t]}$ and computes an output string
>   $y$ such that:
>
> (1) $y \in L$ if and only if there exists $i \in [t]$ such that $x_i \in L$
>
> (2) $\vert y \vert \leq p(Max_{i\in[t]} \vert x_i \vert)$ for some polynomial $p$
>
> (3) The algorithm computes $y$ in at most $q(\sum_{i\in[t]}\vert x_i \vert)$ time for some polynomial $q$

It has been shown that if there exists a distillation algorithm for an $NP$-complete problem, then $coNP \subseteq NP/poly$.  Moreover, $PH = \Sigma_3$.

> See details and discussion in:
>
> - "Infeasibility of Instance Compression and Succinct PCPs for NP"
> - "On Problems Without Polynomial Kernels"
> - "Lower bounds on kernelization"

**Questions:**

- Could there exist a distillation algorithm for a $PSPACE$-complete
  problem?
- If such an algorithm existed, what complexity consequences would we
  get?

Comment: Any further references are welcomed.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: By [this paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/andyd/newlimits.pdf) and polynomial-time many-one reductions, "if there exists a distillation algorithm for an $NP$-complete problem, then" ​ NP $\subseteq$ coAM ​ and "there are non-uniform, statistical zero-knowledge proofs for all languages in NP." ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer This is great!!  Thank you for sharing.  :)

Comment: I now notice that the paper I linked to in fact only needs _compression_, which makes their results more general. ​ In particular, by Theorems 7.1 and 7.3, if there exists _even a compression_ "algorithm for a $PSPACE$-complete problem" then PSPACE has non-uniform statistical zero-knowledge proofs. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thank you again for pointing me to this!  :)

Comment: I don't understand the last part of the question. AFAICS the existence of a distillation algorithm for a PSPACE-complete problem doesn't imply the existence of a dist algo for an NP-complete problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek This is a good point that I didn't realize.  I will make adjustments to my question.  When I was looking at it, I was considering whether a certain parameterized problem has a polynomial kernel which would imply that it has a distillation algorithm.  If this certain PSPACE-complete problem has a polynomial kernel, then a certain NP-complete problem has a polynomial kernel.  So the polynomial kernel for PSPACE does imply for NP, but the distillation for PSPACE might not imply distillation for NP unless I'm missing something.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 15.3 of the recent "Parameterized Algorithms" textbook by Cygan et al. states the following:

"Let $L, R ⊆ \Sigma^*$ be two languages. If there exists an OR-distillation of L into R, then $L\in coNP / poly$"

So, I think that if there exists an OR-distillation from a PSPACE-complete language $L$ to itself, then $PSPACE \subseteq coNP/poly$, i.e. not only does the polynomial-hierarchy collapse, but also PSPACE collapses with it.

Comment: Theorem 7.1 of [the paper I linked to in the comments](http://people.csail.mit.edu/andyd/newlimits.pdf) is strictly qualitatively better. ​ Does Theorem 15.3 of that book handle larger-for-some-parameters error bounds than item 2 of 7.1? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: You stated "also PSPACE collapses with it".  In particular, I believe we get $\Sigma_3 = PSPACE$.  I don't see a way to improve this, but I thought I would ask anyways.  Can we get a better collapse that this?  Say $\Sigma_2 = PSPACE$?